# Retrieve Page Layouts in Source Format

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx, page-layout

How can I get all page layouts from an org in [Source Format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm)?

Some things I've tried

```
# Retrieve

$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout"
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:My_Object__c"
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:My_Object__c-My Object Layout"

=== Retrieved Source
No results found
```

```
# Converting from Metadata Format

# Given these files:
unpackaged/package.xml
unpackaged/layouts/My_Object__c-My Object Layout.layout

$ sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir unpackaged --outputdir src
No results found
```

Manual steps are ok, just need to do this one-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Layouts` were ignored in `.forceignore`

Answer (score 12):

### Retrieving specific layout:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:Account-Retail Account"
```

- Object Name: Account
- Layout Name: Retail Account

Comment: I forget that dash way too often because they use dot notation in other places for seperate things

Answer (score 6):

I also tried the below commands and it worked fine.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x ./manifest/package.xml
```

OR

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Layout
```

You may like to verify if you have the `Layout` attribute added in your `package.xml`

---

This has worked for me in VS Code, if at all you are open to this option.

- Create a Project with Manifest
- In the `package.xml`, specify the layouts (make sure you have it in package.xml), example as below:

  ```
  <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>Layout</name>
  </types>
  ```
- Execute SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org
  [image]

---

Comment: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Layout` worked well for me. I was only interested in Account layouts, so I simply deleted the others.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (answer before retrieved record type rather than page layout as pointed out by David Cheng): 
**Retrieving specific page layout into project (VS code SF CLI):**
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:sobject-pagelayoutname"

**Example:**
Page Layout Name: Equipment Finance
Object: Opportunity

To retrieve the above:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:Opportunity-Equipment Finance"
```

Comment: Your example retrieves the record type, not the layout.